# Google Classroom: In 'createCourse' API, getting "Google_Service_Exception - 401" error

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-classroom

Google Classroom:

I am trying to create course using google-classroom API.

I followed steps:

1. Created new project (in external mode)
2. Enabled 'Google Classroom API'
3. Setup 'OAuth content screen' & 'Credentials' (created 'credentials.json' with 'OAuth Client ID') settings.
4. Installed 'Google Classroom' related library in "CodeIgniter":
   composer require google/apiclient:^2.0

---

My code snippet - PHP CodeIgniter:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
require FCPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Client;
use Google\Service\Classroom;
use Google\Service\Classroom\Course;
use Google\Service\Exception;

class Googleclassroom extends CI_Controller {
    
    function __construct()
    {       
        parent::__construct();      
    }
    
    public function createCourse()
    {       
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('Google Classroom API PHP ');
        $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_COURSES_READONLY);
        $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
        
        $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses");
        $service = new Classroom($client);
        
        $course = new Course([
            'name' => '10th  Biology',
            'section' => 'Period 2',
            'descriptionHeading' => 'Welcome to 10th Grade Biology',
            'description' => 'hi',
            'room' => '301',
            'ownerId' => 'me',
            'courseState' => 'PROVISIONED'
        ]);
        $course = $service->courses->create($course);
        printf("Course created: %s (%s)\n", $course->name, $course->id);
    }
}
```

When I am hitting following url in browser, I am getting error as mentioned below:
http://baseUrl/Googleclassroom/createCourse

**Error:**

An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Google_Service_Exception

Message: { "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22), "errors": [ { "message": "Invalid Credentials", "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "location": "Authorization", "locationType": "header" } ], "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" } }

Please suggest me solution on this.

Comment: Sounds like you only set up client credentials, but the endpoint needs a _user_ access token?

Comment: @CBroe Please suggest me modifications in my code snippet. Also let me know, where I will get token json file in google cloud console.

Comment: I am not sure what exact kind of credentials you need, that should be in the documentation. If this really needs a OAuth 2.0 access token, then you would have to implement https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/main/docs/oauth-web.md#obtaining-oauth-20-access-tokens

Comment: You're missing the part where you redirect the user to authenticate with OAuth, then get the authorization code with a callback to call `$client->authenticate($code)`, then you can use `$client->getAccessToken()`. Right now your `$client` just has the app credentials but no user authentication. I don't have a PHP environment to post a good code sample but try to review [these docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#redirecting) closely from step 2 to step 5, which is what you are skipping. And from step one you also need to define`$client->setRedirectUri()`

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, I have added missing token script. Its working properly now.